# Suitcrm dynamic drop down

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am tried to create new dynamic drops downs inside suitCRM site using studio . But i can only create drop down with static datas

[image: Dynamic Drop Down]

click on the edit button near drop down list its looks like

[image]

i can only add new static values for drop down .
My question is about to create drop down with dynamic values (Eg : fill drop down with lead name and id - all lead names and its ids ) . How it is possible .any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using customization:

1. Create one dropdown using studio. e.g. `lead_dropdown`
2. You will find entry of dropdown in `/custom/include/language/en_us.lang.php`
3. In same file make a database connection as below:

> ```
>    include_once('include/database/DBManagerFactory.php');  
>    $db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();  
>    $leads = array();  
>    $qryLead = "select a.id, a.name from leads"; $leadRes = $db->query($qryLead);
>
>    $leadNum = $db->getRowCount($leadRes); if($leadNum > 0) 
>    {
>     while ($hrow = $db->fetchByAssoc($leadRes))  
>      {
>         $leads[$hrow['id']] = $hrow['name'];
>      }  
>    }  
>    $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['cl_lead_drodown'] = $leads;
> ```

Hope this will help you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi sAcH . Thanks for your reply . Its work like a charm . can i  add multiple global variables for various drop downs  in the same file?

Comment: can you explain in detail?